# UIDeviceOrientation Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, uideviceorientation

In order to receive `UIDeviceOrientation` change notifications, one must do two things:

1. call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` on `UIDevice`
2. register for the notifications.

Here's my question:

Let's say I have two view controllers who want to receive these notifications and the first calls `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` and registers, then the second does the same.  Now my first VC unloads and unregisters and calls `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`.  Will the second VC continue to receive these notifications even though the first VC "turned them off"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The documentation for the `begin…` method says so, at least sort-of:

> You may nest calls to this method safely, but you should always match
>   each call with a corresponding call to the
>   `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` method.

This kind of interface is usually implemented using some counter. Each `begin…` method increments the counter, each `end…` method decrements it. The notifications are sent as long as the counter is greater than zero.

Comment: I read that documentation, and although your "counter" explanation sounds reasonable, I wasn't satisfied with the documentation's explanation that what you suggest (counter implementation) is actually implemented.  I guess I could test it easy enough...